# Converting dictionary to dataframe, and then melting / stacking columns to rows

Tags: python, pandas, stack, melt

I am a bit confused about how to use `melt` or `stack` correctly in order to transform my dataframe.

Currently have a dataframe which looks as follows:

[image]

My objective is to transform this data frame, (probably using `melt` or `stack`), and I'm having some trouble doing so.  My objective is to have my dataframe look like this:

[image]

My data is currently stored in a `dict` :

```
{'K_T1': [84.51865079365093,
  84.51865079365093,
  83.80912698412698,
  83.80912698412698,
  86.56468253968255,
  86.56468253968255],
 'K_T2': [77.26309523809515,
  77.26309523809515,
  77.57777777777771,
  77.57777777777771,
  77.09999999999992,
  77.09999999999992],
 'Z_T1': [83.80912698412698,
  83.80912698412698,
  86.61111111111107,
  86.61111111111107,
  87.81746031746032,
  87.81746031746032],
 'Z_T2': [77.57777777777771,
  77.57777777777771,
  75.8619047619048,
  75.8619047619048,
  74.79007936507927,
  74.79007936507927]}
```

Pseudocode:

- Convert my `dict` to a dataframe: `K_Z_Averages_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(K_Z_Averages)`
- Add a column, for `Part Name`.
- Identify if the initial column name has T1 or T2 listed and place it into the correct column, `T1` or `T2` using `melt` or `stack`.

Thanks for any support which can be offered!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) first by `_` in columns, then reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) with some data cleaning:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.split('_', expand=True)
df = (df.stack(0)
        .sort_index(level=1)
        .rename_axis([None, 'Part Name'])
        .reset_index(level=1)
        .reset_index(drop=True))
print (df)
   Part Name         T1         T2
0          K  84.518651  77.263095
1          K  84.518651  77.263095
2          K  83.809127  77.577778
3          K  83.809127  77.577778
4          K  86.564683  77.100000
5          K  86.564683  77.100000
6          Z  83.809127  77.577778
7          Z  83.809127  77.577778
8          Z  86.611111  75.861905
9          Z  86.611111  75.861905
10         Z  87.817460  74.790079
11         Z  87.817460  74.790079
```

Another idea with [`wide_to_long`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html) and rename columns with change order before and after `_`:

```
df.columns = [f'{b}_{a}' for a, b in df.columns.str.split('_')]

df = (pd.wide_to_long(df.reset_index(),
                      stubnames=['T1','T2'],
                      i='index',
                      j='Part Name',
                      sep='_',
                      suffix='\w+')
       .reset_index(level=1).reset_index(drop=True))
print (df)  
   Part Name         T1         T2
0          K  84.518651  77.263095
1          K  84.518651  77.263095
2          K  83.809127  77.577778
3          K  83.809127  77.577778
4          K  86.564683  77.100000
5          K  86.564683  77.100000
6          Z  83.809127  77.577778
7          Z  83.809127  77.577778
8          Z  86.611111  75.861905
9          Z  86.611111  75.861905
10         Z  87.817460  74.790079
11         Z  87.817460  74.790079
```